# Out Of Memory Error: Java Heap Space - PreparedStatement MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

```
void insert(ArrayList myList){
       conn = openDBConnection(); //Database Connection
       Iterator iterator = myList.iterator();
       while(iterator.hasNext()){
           insertIntoDB((myClass)iterator.next(),conn);
       }
       closeDBConnection();
   }

   void insertIntoDB(myClass myObject, Connection conn){
     String query = "insert into myTable values(?,?)";
     PreparedStatement myStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
     myStatement.setInt(1,myObject.getMyKey());
     myStatement.setInt(2,myObject.getMyValue());
     myStatement.execute();
    }
```

In the above code `myList` is an `arrayList` of objects with more than 1.2M entries. I am getting the following error after inserting around 1000 records:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:437)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.clientPrepareStatement(Connection.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4829)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:4734)
    at com.att.research.space.SpaceDaoImpl.insertMapping(SpaceDaoImpl.java:99)
    at com.att.research.space.ElementMappingLoader.insertMappingData(ElementMappingLoader.java:68)
    at com.att.research.space.CorrelationEngine.loadMappingFiles(CorrelationEngine.java:69)
    at com.att.research.space.CorrelationEngine.main(CorrelationEngine.java:25)
```

I tried using `System.gc()` inside the iterator loop. But I don't think it is a good way to code and also it is consuming lot of CPU cycle.

The above code is a sample code format of my original code.

Comment: did you try to increase heap by jvm options?

Comment: No I didn't try that but I knew that is also an option. I want to ensure that my code is proper

Comment: It's not.  You get the error because your code isn't right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run out of memory because you **did not close the statement**. This is called a resource leak.

Using try-with-resources (Java 7+):

```
void insertIntoDB(myClass myObject, Connection conn){
    String query = "insert into myTable values(?,?)";
    try (PreparedStatement myStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        myStatement.setInt(1,myObject.getMyKey());
        myStatement.setInt(2,myObject.getMyValue());
        myStatement.execute();
    }
}
```

Pre-Java 7:

```
void insertIntoDB(myClass myObject, Connection conn){
    String query = "insert into myTable values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement myStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    try {
        myStatement.setInt(1,myObject.getMyKey());
        myStatement.setInt(2,myObject.getMyValue());
        myStatement.execute();
    } finally {
        myStatement.close();
    }
}
```

As others have suggested, you should re-use your statement, but it's the missing `close()` that's the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `PreparedStatement` is to create it once and bind variables.

Here's how I'd suggest that you write it:

```
private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "insert into myTable values(?,?)";

public int insert(Connection c, List<MyClass> myList) {
    int numRows = 0;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;    
    try {
        ps = c.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
        for (MyClass x : myList) {
            ps.setInt(1, x.getMyKey());
            ps.setInt(2, x.getMyValue());
            numRows += ps.executeUpdate();          
        }
    } finally {
       close(ps);
    }
    return numRows;
}
```

I left some details for you to figure out (e.g. that close method).

A word of advice: Lose that affection for naming everything "MyFoo".  Your code is unreadable with such a naming convention.  Think more carefully about how you name things.

Comment: I agree that one of the points of a `PreparedStatement` is reuse, but to me the *primary* point is the use of parameter markers. Main advantage is prevention of SQL Injection issues, but I use `PreparedStatement` even for one-off statements with a single `int` parameter, since that improves server statement caching.

Answer (score 1):

move the statement out of the loop and user addBatch() and executeBatch instead

Comment: +1 for both suggestions.  Excellent.  I left out the batch from my example below, but it's the right idea.

Comment: @duffymo still  with 6 . If 7 try with resources would have  reduced the lines :-)

Comment: Thanks TTM. Does it close Sql resources like PreparedStatement and ResultSet?

Comment: yes if created within try() like the code in @Andreas

Comment: Can you have both PreparedStatement and ResultSet, as you would for a query?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding memory leaks with finally block should definitely be addressed first; however if its just a very large resultset; I found this useful:

http://benjchristensen.com/2008/05/27/mysql-jdbc-memory-usage-on-large-resultset/

namely adding

```
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Before runing stmt.executeQuery();